# getting started with linux kernel programming

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am from  embedded systems development.I have decent knowledge about  c , c++ and micro-controllers. But I want to pursue my career in Linux kernel  programming.

For this I also have some decent knowledge of operating systems concepts and Linux kernel. But I need to know from where to start for Linux kernel programming. I have learnt a bit of Linux kernel programming, but due to my work which is completely different from Linux, I am not able to recall things.

Comment: Contribute to some kernel module. Ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: Since you do embedded stuff, do you write device drivers ? You can start looking from the device driver perspective.